# Searching for files using sub-directory wildcard (glob)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a main configuration file `config.yml`.

In it, I would like to specify list of 'included' config files.
The includes can be resolved using search patterns, which include wild cards.

For example:

```
includes:
  - /plugins/**/config.yml
  - /etc/**/config.yml
```

Currently, the only way to search for files in .net is by calling `Directory.GetFile`, but this method has to receive explicitly `SearchOption` whether to include all subdirectories or only the top one in the search.

It doesn't support "search all sub directories" (`/**/`) pattern.

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: The file pattern is called a “glob”. I would look into glob libraries that can do what you want. To my knowledge there is no such functionality in the core libraries.

Comment: I would accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file pattern is called a “glob”. To my knowledge there is no functionality in the core libraries to handle globs. I would look for a third-party glob library.